# Angular with RxJS: be sure service's constructor using http.get is finished before call method

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

In Angular 6 I have a `ConfigService` that requires the constructor to have finished to work well:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Subscribable, Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    public configKeys: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get('config/config.json').subscribe(
            data => {
                this.configKeys = data;
            },
            (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                console.log (err.message);
            }
        );
    }

    getDocBaseRoute() :string{
        return this.configKeys.docBaseRoute;
    }

    getAuthenticationBaseRoute() :  Subscription {
        return this.configKeys.authenticationBaseRoute;
    }
}
```

An issue is triggered when I try to call a method of the service:

```js
this.baseUrl = this.configservice.getAuthenticationBaseRoute();
```

Actually  at this moment `configKeys` is undefined so `return this.configKeys.authenticationBaseRoute;` throws an error.

So could you help me to you know how I could be sure constructor has been finished before methods of the service are called?

Comment: Why do you not just return the Observable itself to the caller? In case the function is called multiple times, you could introduce some local caching by storing the config keys in a property (i.e. configKeys as you already named it), checking for its existence, and return a manually constructed observable using the cached value (using `of(this.configKeys)`) if the property already holds a value.

Comment: @JanWendland yes i will try that, thx

Comment: if you declare configKeys as empty object: configKeys:any={}; you received undefined, but nor an error. But yes, your problem must be resolved by using a cache value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use RxJS throughout for this to work properly.

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { shareReplay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    private configuration: Observable<any>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getDocBaseRoute(): Observable<string> {
        return this.getConfiguration().pipe(map(data => data.docBaseRoute));
    }

    getAuthenticationBaseRoute(): Observable<any> {
        return this.getConfiguration().pipe(map(data => data.authenticationBaseRoute));
    }

    private getConfiguration(): Observable<any> {
        if(!this.configuration) {
            this.configuration = this.http.get('config/config.json').pipe(
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => console.log(err.message)),
                shareReplay()
            );
        }

        return this.configuration;
    }
}
```

Note that I store the `Observable`, not the result in a property. If you don't do this and call `getConfiguration()` multiple times, then due to timing multiple HTTP calls might occur. Using the RxJS `shareReplay` operator is also vital for this.

Usage:

```js
this.configservice.getAuthenticationBaseRoute().subscribe(baseRoute => this.baseUrl = baseRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of doing this, that would be against the concept of RxJS.

This is more a problem of conception in my opinion, you could have different solutions to handle this:

1. Define a default value for `configKeys` so that `getAuthenticationBaseRoute` never fails.
2. Handle the case where `configKeys` is `null` inside `getAuthenticationBaseRoute`, and have it return `undefined`. But you must also handle this case where you call `getAuthenticationBaseRoute`.
3. Make so the component/service/whatever that calls `getAuthenticationBaseRoute` can't call it before `configKeys` is defined inside `ConfigService`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a way to do it : 
transforme observable into a promise using toPromise()

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    public configKeys: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    async getGestionDocumentBaseRoute(): Promise<string> {
        await this.initialize();
        return this.configKeys.gestionDocumentBaseRoute;
    }

    private async initialize(): Promise<boolean> {
        if (!this.configKeys) {
            await this.http.get('config/config.json').toPromise()
                .then(
                    data => {
                        this.configKeys = data;
                    }
                )
                .catch(
                    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                        console.log(err.message);
                        return false;
                    }
                );
        }
        return true;
    }

    async getAuthenticationBaseRoute(): Promise<string> {
        await this.initialize();
        return this.configKeys.authenticationBaseRoute;
    }
}
```